# [ERROR: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.]

Tags: flutter, navigator

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart': Failed assertion: line 2845 pos 18: '!navigator._debugLocked': is not true.

That bug when run my app. I'm not fix. I try below code but not working

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, PageTransition(
                          type: PageTransitionType.leftToRight,
                          child: HomeScreen(),
                        ));

                      });
```

Comment: what are you trying to archive ? Can you include more snippet that will reproduce the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Stop your running app and reinstall the app to device
this is state issue

Answer (score 0):

On my end, I had the same issue after a few days of generating the release app to deploy on the Play Store.

By using the solution above, I followed the following steps:

- Uninstall the previous APK in your device/emulator
- Run `flutter clean`
- Run `flutter pub get`
- After run your app